# From LengthAwarePaginator from Controoler to data in blade..?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to get LengthAwarePaginator data in blade. but i don't know why can't get data..

error say `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

`\Log::debug($data['user'))` is fine like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG97O.png)

but i don't know why i can't get data..

please help me..

```php
//ExampleController.php
$users = Chat::datePeriodSearch($data['start_date'], $data['end_date'])->selectPaginate($data['per_page']);

       $itemsTransformed = $users->getCollection()
        ->map(function($item){
            return [
                'id' => $item->id,
                'name' => $item->user_id,
                'pgid' => $item->pgid
            ];
        });

        $data['users'] = new LengthAwarePaginator(
            $itemsTransformed,
            $users->total(),
            $users->perPage(),
            $users->currentPage(),
            [
                'path' => \Request::url(),
                'query' => [
                    'page' => $users->currentPage()
                ]
            ]
        );

return ('example.view',compact('data'));
```

```php
//exampleView.blade.php
@forelse( $data['users'] as $user)
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a class="single-user-name" href="{{route('total_statistics.show', $user->id)}}">{{ $user->first_name . ', ' . $user->last_name }}</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace this

```
$user->id
```

By

```
$user['id']
```